# Need to show list of items in Chatbot using .Net Core bot framework

Tags: .net-core, botframework, chatbot, azure-qna-maker

Need to show list of items on button click from knowledge base on Chatbot using Microsoft Botframework

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should take a look at the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/index-bf-sdk?view=azure-bot-service-4.0)? There you will find details on how the bot framework works, as well as numerous samples. There is also a "How-To" section that details how to implement various features, including data display mechanisms such as cards or response messages.